# Как передать путь к файлу и название файла в виде двух значений переменных?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу реализовать скрипт таким образом, чтобы человек вводил путь к файлу-источнику, путь к файлу-назначению, файл-источник и файл-приёмщик без вмешательства в код. Значения скрипт принимает, но когда дело доходит до открытия файла, скрипт выдаёт ошибку. Вот код

```
path = [0] * 2
sourcefile = 0
destinationfile = 0

print("Please write your source path:")
input(path[0])
print("Please write your destination path:")
input(path[1])
print("Source name of your file is ")
input(sourcefile)
print("Destination name of your file is ")
input(destinationfile)

with open(r"%s"+"%s" % (path[0], sourcefile), 'r') as file_in:
```

Проблема начинается на моменте `with open`. Кто знает, прошу помочь.

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: Еще добавлю, что проблемы у вас на самом деле начинаются на строчке ``input(path[0])``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь

```
print("Please write your source path:")
input(path[0])
```

вы совершенно неправильно используете `input`.

На самом деле, аргументом у него нужно указывать тот текст, который вы хотите показать пользователю. А полученное значение `input` возвращает как результат, и его нужно явно присваивать переменной.

То есть эти две строчки нужно переписать так:

```
path[0] = input("Please write your source path: ")
```

И остальные инпуты переписать аналогично.

Comment: я обновил запись. Можете глянуть и помочь с ошибкой?

Comment: Это уже другая проблема. Данный ресурс служит в первую очередь для сохранения экспертных знаний. Поэтому если вы исправляете вопрос, на который дан ответ, на совершенно другой вопрос, то вы делаете бесполезным для других пользователей ответы на первый вопрос. Задайте отдельный вопрос, а в этом вопросе вы можете отметить мой ответ как решение.

Comment: готово. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956062/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-python

Comment: Готово, ответил