# Как записать путь файла с помощью двух переменных?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу реализовать скрипт таким образом, чтобы можно было ввести путь к файлу-источнику, путь к файлу-назначению, файл-источник и файл-назначения без вмешательства в код. Значения скрипт принимает, но когда дело доходит до открытия файла, скрипт выдаёт ошибку.
Вот код:

```
path = [0] * 2
sourcefile = 0
destinationfile = 0

path[0] = input("Write your path to source")
path[1] = input("Write your path to destination")
sourcefile = input("Write your file-source name")
destinationfile = input("Write your file-destination name")

with open(r"%s"+"%s" % (path[0], sourcefile), 'r') as file_in:
```

Проблема начинается на моменте `with open`.

Как можно сделать по-другому?

Comment: Вы научитесь уже читать текст ошибки и копировать его в вопрос.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, _конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код_ для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы __без явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

Для склейки путей в python есть специальной модуль [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) в нем есть функция `os.path.join` для постройки путей лучше всего пользоваться именно ей, вам нужно что-то такое

```
import os


def main():
    path = [0] * 2
    sourcefile = 0
    destinationfile = 0

    path[0] = input("Write your path to source")
    path[1] = input("Write your path to destination")
    sourcefile = input("Write your file-source name")
    destinationfile = input("Write your file-destination name")

    file_path = os.path.join(path[0], sourcefile)

    # check if file exists before try to open it
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        print("No such file")
        return

    with open(file_path, 'r') as file_in:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот это

```
r"%s"+"%s" % (path[0], sourcefile)
```

не будет работать. Так как оператор `%` имеет больший приоритет, чем `+`, то интерпретатор будет сначала пытаться впихнуть два значения `path[0]` и `sourcefile` в строчку `"%s"` , где есть подстановочное место только для одного значения.

Нужно либо явно указать приоритет с помощью скобок:

```
(r"%s"+"%s") % (path[0], sourcefile)
```

либо (что гораздо лучше) просто написать так:

```
r"%s%s" % (path[0], sourcefile)
```

Впрочем, в соседнем ответе предложили ещё более лучший вариант с использованием модуля `os`

Answer (score 1):

Кроме [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) можно также воспользоваться относительно новым модулем [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (встроен в Python 3.x, для Python 2.x существует в качестве дополнительного модуля - `pip install pathlib2`) :

```
try:
    from pathlib import Path       # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    from pathlib2 import Path      # Python 2.x  (pip install pathlib2)

file_path = Path(path[0]) / sourcefile
with open(file_path) as file_in:
    # ...
```